# Why performance diffs between Flux.range and Flux.range().flatmap(Flux.range())?

Tags: spring, netty, reactor, spring-webclient

I'm using spring webclient based on netty to initiate massive http requests, assuming:

`total = page * cnt`

here `total` is the total request.

One option is to use `Flux.range(1, total)` as:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tid1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Mono<String> total(@RequestParam(value = "total") Integer total) {
        long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Flux.range(1, total)
                .flatmap(n -> {
                    // WebClient POST request here
                })
                .then(Mono.just(total))
                .map(n -> {
                    long ms1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long du = n * 1000 / (ms1-ms);
                    String res = "Num: " + n + ", QPS: " + du;
                    log.error(res);
                    return res;
                })
                ;
    }
```

Another option is splitting `total` into `page` pages, each page takes `cnt` requests:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Mono<String> paging(@RequestParam(value = "page") Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "cnt") Integer cnt) {
        long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Flux.range(1, page)
                .flatMap(n -> {
                    return Flux.range(1, cnt)
                            .flatMap(k -> {
                                // WebClient POST request here
                            });
                })
                .then(Mono.just(cnt * page))
                .map(n -> {
                    long ms1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long du = n * 1000 / (ms1-ms);
                    String res = "Num: " + n + ", QPS: " + du;
                    log.error(res);
                    return res;
                })
        ;
    }
```

I found that the performance diffs a lot between these options, the first one has a QPS of 12500, and second has a QPS of 7000(QPS is the requests number processed in one second).

Unfortunately I must adopt paging solution, and I wonder why these two approachs has so much difference?

Comment: In the first example you seemingly initiate http calls in a map operator instead of flatMap. As some part of the code is left out it's difficult to say what's happening exactly, but that doesn't seem correct and potentially can make a big difference in your measurement (it is possible those calls are not even executed if they are not subscribed).

Comment: My bad, actually it's flatmap. I was trying to replace webclient post with another sync calculation code block to see the performance.

Comment: And what is the value for total? How big number are we talking about? Is it possible that the server you call is slowing down because of the number of calls?

Comment: total is a big number like millions.

Comment: Did you try this example with a real network call wherever you have "WebClient POST request here", or are the numbers arrived at using some compute work in that block?